# Dependency Source Code Debug React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, dependencies, libraries, chrome-debugging

I am working on a local dependency/library for my react native app.

I want to debug that locally added dependency for a react native app in my chrome/Web Storm debugger. Debugger connection is successful, however for library files only '**dist**' folder is available to debug. I am unable to run breakpoints from 'src' folder.

Please help me how I can debug typescript files from dependency '**src**' folder?